# Очень сложная выборка

Tags: mysql

В общем есть две таблицы: группы (id, название) и пользователи (id, id группы в которой состоит, рейтинг). Нужно найти количество групп, среднее арифметическое рейтинга членов которых больше среднего арифметического какой-то конкретной группы. 
Бьюсь уже очень долго, никак не выходит... Вот так ошибка, хотя это самое лучшее решение из тех, что у меня было.. Моя задача вообще выполнима без php?

```
    SELECT
    AVG(rating) as this_rating, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*), u.AVG(rating) as avgr
    LEFT JOIN users u ON groups.id=u.group_id
    FROM groups 
    WHERE avgr>this_rating
    ) as rating_rang
    FROM users 
    WHERE group_id='$group_id'
```

Примеры таблиц
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b01882

Comment: сделайте sqlfiddle с примерами таблиц.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b01882

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
SELECT
  all_groups.group_id,
  all_groups.rating
FROM 
  (SELECT AVG(rating) rating  
    FROM users
    WHERE group_id = '$group_id') this_group
JOIN 
  (SELECT group_id, AVG(rating) rating
    FROM users
    GROUP BY group_id) all_groups
ON all_groups.rating > this_group.rating
```

Количество сами посчитаете?

Comment: получаем средний рейтинг для конкретной группы, фильтруем по нему средний рейтинг остальных групп...

Comment: А если теперь я хочу добавить ещё один параметр к группам, и считать только те, у которых он совпадает с этим же параметром конкретной группы?

Comment: Просто полей добавьте в подзапросы. и добавьте в необходимые условия в `ON`.

Comment: Вообще если честно нихрена не разобрался, как искать только среди групп, у которых поле theme='1'...

Comment: А, нет, однако получилось